# Save Watchdog ISR Return Address in EEPROM

Tags: interrupt, atmega328, watchdog

If the WDT ever fires, from the ISR I save some info in EEPROM for later diagnostics before I drive the reset pin. Stack size, heap size, etc.

It might also be useful to know where the code was when the WDT fired, i.e. the ISR's return address. How do I get that?

Comment: What architrcture?

Comment: AVR… Arduino Pro Mini atmega328p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GCC has a handy function `__builtin_return_address(depth)` which should do what you want.  To get the return address of the current function (which should be the same whether it's a normal function or an ISR on AVR) you set the `depth` to 0:

```cpp
void *addr = __builtin_return_address(0);
```

**EDIT**

The address returned above is a word address. Multiply by two to get a byte address as found in the disassembly from `avr-objdump -SC firmware.elf >disassembled.txt`

The latter is found at `~/.platformio/packages/toolchain-atmelavr/bin/avr-objdump`

Comment: Well, *that* was easy… thanks! Next exercise is to figure out where that is in the code.

Comment: I didn't articulate that very well… next exercise is to find out where that return address is in the code (or in space) to get a clue what went wrong.

Comment: @EricNelson: Disassemble the .elf file using `avr-objdump -SC`.

Comment: @EdgarBonet YES!! Oh, man, does this ever take me back to the 90s.  Poring over disassembled code, counting cycles, rearranging code to see if we can eke out a few more whatevers per second to win a benchmark.

Comment: "addr2line" might be a handy tool, too.